# Swift HTTPS error

Tags: swift, https

Can't understand, what is wrong in this code? It doesn't work...
If I try request HTTP , It work, but HTTPS doesn't work.
Please help or give some literature.

CODE:

```
@IBAction func registrationAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let name      = cView.nameTextField.text!
    let email     = cView.emailTextField.text!
    let password  = cView.passwordTextField.text!

    let json      = [ "name"     : name ,
                      "email"    : email ,
                      "password" : password ] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    let urlPatch  = "https://128.32.136.40:8080/ewrdsf/sdffs"

    let url     = NSURL(string: urlPatch)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    do {
        request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: .PrettyPrinted)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    let session  = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (let data, let response, let error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        print(dataString!)
    }

    dataTask.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the App Transport Security Settings in your app plist file. Right click on your plist file and open as source code then add this key.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

For more info see this: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/703/